How to use a custom taxonomy term name as meta_value in a get_posts query
I am stuck with something which I am sure is simple, but I cannot find an answer online.
I have two custom post types ('walks' and 'features') which I am trying to query using a code number which is unique to each 'walk'. 'Features' can relate to one or more 'walks' and this is stored on the 'features' cpt as a custom taxonomy 'feature-on-route-number'. I am trying to use the taxonomy value (or values) and to list the walk (or walks) that the feature relates to. The  corresponding number stored on the 'walks' cpt in a custom field ('route_number') '.
I have tried the following code:
$routenumber = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'feature-on-route-number', '', ', ', '' );

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'walks',
    'meta_key'      => 'route_number',
    'meta_value'    => $routenumber              
));

// processes on the results

This returns no results. I have tested the query by adding actual values for 'meta_value', and by assigning a single value to $routenumber and it works. So I am guessing the problem is with using a taxonomy to set the variable. Is there a simple way to fix this? Or do I need a second query to loop through the taxonomy?
Many thanks

Examine the value of $routenumber returned by get_the_term_list (just echo it out).  get_the_terms might be better here.  Either way, you'll need another step to extract the route number.

I'm not completely following your setup, but get_the_term_list will return a string internally delimited by a comma, and you are passing that directly to get_posts. If there's only one item, that should work, however if there's more than one you will end up with 1, 2 or similar, and the default comparison is =. You could try setting meta_compare to IN, and I think that will satisfy the clause then.

If you ever have a question about why a specific query isn't working, I would strongly recommend inspecting the actual query that is generated. This will give you a string that you can enter into a SQL tool and bypass WordPress and PHP to see exactly what the database thinks about it, and if you are comfortable with SQL it can sometimes be very obvious what needs to be changed.

Don't use get_the_term_list() WordPress function for that, as it gives an HTML string of linked term names.
Use instead one of the following related WordPress functions:

get_the_terms()
wp_get_post_terms()

Assuming that "feature-on-route-number" is the correct custom taxonomy, try:
$routenumber = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'feature-on-route-number'); 

if ( $routenumber && !is_wp_error($routenumber) ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'walks',
        'meta_key'          => 'route_number',
        'meta_value'        => current($routenumber)->name,              
    ));

    // processes on the results
}

It should better work.

Addition (handling one or multiple terms)
It is possible to handle an array of meta values by defining the meta_compare argument to "IN" for that meta query.
Also when using wp_get_post_terms() you can define the returned terms as term names directly, using the third function argument.
The code:
$routenumbers = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'feature-on-route-number', ['fields' => 'names']); 

if ( $routenumbers && !is_wp_error($routenumbers) ) {
    $posts = get_posts( array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'walks',
        'meta_key'          => 'route_number',
        'meta_value'        => $routenumbers,   
        'meta_compare'      => 'IN',              
    ));

    // processes on the results
}


Thank you LoicTheAztec for the code edit. It worked to produce one result, but missed multiple terms. I added a taxonomy loop and it seemed to work. Not sure if this is the most elegant approach though.
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'feature-on-route-number' );
foreach( $terms as $term){
    $routenumber = $term->name;     
    
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'walks',
        'meta_key'      => 'route_number',
        'meta_value'    => $routenumber                                    
    ));

    // processes on the results
}

